# SqlCommand-class force SELECT only?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I'm developing a application that's for SQL-surveillance, it's just a console application that will run each 5min on a bunch of servers. It has a config file with connection string and sql query. The thing is I would like the program to accept SELECT queries only.

I colleague told me he thought I could set something in the SqlCommand-class but I've been googling for a while without any success. Anyone got a clean solution on my problem? I've thought about searching the query for different words but it's to much that can go wrong.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Granting privileges would be the better way to go, but you can still parse the statement, even if its a series of SQL commands, using something like this:

```
bool OkToRun = true;
foreach(string s in TheQueryString.Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    if (!s.Trim().ToUpper().StartsWith("SELECT "))
        OkToRun = false;
```

Comment: Agree that the granting privileges would be the best solution, but in this case the config file gives the program the user.. I'll go with your code example until I find anything better! Thanks

Comment: Not all SELECT queries will lead with the `SELECT` keyword e.g. those that employ a CTE.

Answer (score 2):

The database table itself can be restricted.
you can revoke all permission but select from the user of your application.
search for `REVOKE/GRANT` commands for SQL-SERVER.

Comment: Since the config file include the connection string the the application itself doesn't provide a user.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the application. This REVOKE command should run on the database itself. The application still uses a user to connect the database.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be possible unless your application builds the entire SELECT statement itself.

The issue is that even if you ensure the first word is SELECT there is nothing stopping a malicuous user terminating the command and then issuing an EXEC or UPDATE statement also.

The best solution is to ensure that the user account referenced in your connection string has limited permissions to the SQL objects and thus only SELECT from supported objects will work.

Comment: That's what I ment by "I've thought about searching the query for different words but it's to much that can go wrong." =/